# CentOS log high cpu usage

Tags: linux, centos, logging, cpu-usage

I have a CentOS server running on a VPS via Virtuozoo containers.

I feel like there are high CPU usage spikes. Is there a way I can log every time CPU usage goes beyond a certain limit lets say 50%.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Monit](http://mmonit.com/monit/) can do that:

```
check system localhost.localdomain.tld
    if loadavg (1min) > 5 for 6 cycles then alert
    if loadavg (5min) > 2 for 3 cycles then alert
    if loadavg (15min) > 2 for 2 cycles then alert
    if memory usage > 90% for 6 cycles then alert
    if cpu usage (user) > 75% for 6 cycles then alert
    if cpu usage (system) > 75% for 6 cycles then alert
    if cpu usage (wait) > 75% for 6 cycles then alert
```

Answer (score 0):

Look into munin and graphite, both are excellent and free tools for system management.

Comment: wouldn't munin just monitor things like apache instead ?

Comment: Munin can log all kinds of things.  Here's an example:  http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/46/cpur.png/

Comment: is that in the normal configuration ? if no , how do configure it to log CPU ?

Comment: Your question is a little out of the scope of this comment.  Here's one approach.  http://www.howtoforge.com/server_monitoring_monit_munin

Comment: If this is an _answer_, answering the question shouldn't be out of scope. If this is just a comment, it shouldn't be an _answer_.